# Firebase add data if user actually created it

Tags: firebase, firebase-security

So, I'm into Firebase security rules. There is one security flaw I havn't really figured out how to solve. Lets say I have the structure below. When creating a new "group" I will also place the $refId within the "groups" section for the user actually created the group. Let's say that "John Doe" creates a group and the group ID is also added to his list of groups. My rules says that only John Doe may edit the group since it is in his list of groups.

But if Jane Doe authenticates and adds the group ID to the list of her groups she will also be able to edit the group. How do I solve that scenario?

Do I also need a list of user IDs in each group whom are allegeable to edit the group? Or maybe create an empty group first and have some security rules saying you only may add the group ID to the list if it is empty, and after that populate the group with data? What are the best way to solve this?

```
users: {
    "$uid": {
        name: "John Doe",
        groups: {
            "$refId": true,
            "$refId": true
        }
    },
    "$uid": {
        name: "Jane Doe",
        groups: {
            "$refId": true
        }
    }
},
groups: {
    "$refId": {
        title: "Group 1"
    },
    "$refId": {
        title: "Group 2"
    }
}
```

Comment: How about giving each group an owner and basing edit permissions on that? How about listing people with edit permissions under the group? What about keeping a list of administrators? What have you tried so far and what are the constraints?

Comment: I actually thought of having a list of users under each group as well. Maybe that would work. But now I'm thinking of creating permissions instead. Like having user permissions which contain a list of users having that permission and storing the ID of the permissions instead. I think I will solve this anyway :)